# How do I enter race results in my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models in my app: Athletes, Races, and Results. An Athlete has many results, a Race has many results, and a Result belongs to an Athlete and a Race. Each race has exactly 12 results.

As a beginning Rails developer, I'm having trouble understanding how to create the web form for entering the 12 race results. Should I maintain Results as a separate resource, or nest them under Races? In my controller, would I create 12 instances of a result object under the New action? How do I submit the appropriate race_id for each instance?

If you could help me clarify my thinking on this problem, and point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are several ways to approach this. You certainly could nest `Results` under `Races`, but then it becomes a question of whether you're creating the `Results` at the same time as their `Race` or not (this is worth thinking about because you need to know how to tie your `Results` to your `Race`, e.g. does each `Result` form have a `race_id` as a hidden field? If so the `Race` probably needs to already exist). But in either case this would probably be 12 `Result` forms with `Result.new` as the object.

Comment: Races will be created first, and then results will be added later. Would each Result form have a race_id as a hidden field in that case? I think that's where my problem is. I'm having a hard time understanding how to tie these two models together

Comment: Exactly. Each Result form has a `race_id`. So when you bring up the `edit` form for a `Race`, you can render 12 instances of the partial for a new `Result` and pass in the `@race` object, and then that partial can use the `id` of that object in a hidden field called `race_id`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to nest your results if they have unique and auto-generated IDs, but you can if you think it makes you application easier to use or program.

Your web form should probably be based on the use case of entering 12 athletes as they ranked for a single race.  That means you could use multiple HTML inputs for each of the results:

```
<input type="hidden" name="race[results_attributes][][rank]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="race[results_attributes][][athlete_id]" />
<input type="hidden" name="race[results_attributes][][rank]" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="race[results_attributes][][athlete_id]" />
```

You could then modify your race model to accept inputs for results:

```
class Race
  has_many :results
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :results
end
```

And simply pass the attributes in an update statement:

```
Race.find(params[:id]).update_attributes params[:race]
```